# MAUI Entry on windows doesn't bring up virtual keyboard when clicked

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2022, maui

As the title said, MAUI (6.0, maui7 not tested yet) programs on windows 10, when a Entry is clicked, the windows virtual keyboard is not bring up. The keyboard does bring up when I click on Edge's address bar, or search bar on the computer. Any way to fix this?

Environment:
MAUI 6.0.548.0
VS : 17.4.3
Win: 10.0.19044.2364

Comment: Actually, you can use the `win+ctrl+o` to open and close the virtual keyboard.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT that's right, but unacceptable. I've tested another winform program, a java program,  virtual keyboard is ok.